# Complex 301 redirect from state abbreviation to state full name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following structure of the url www.sample.com/state-abbriviation(2 letters)/category/page.htm

I need to redirect it to the following URL www.sample.com/state-name/page/id.

My question is, how can I dynamically replace state abbriviation(nm,tx) with full state name(newmexico,texas), but keep the rest according to above stated structure?

Comment: Show some incoming and mapped URL examples at least, please. Too much left to guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda complex to do with htaccess. How will htaccess know page and id?

Better redirect everything to a index.php and let php handle it... which will also be kinda complex :p